# Can a function return a function that isn't a lambda?

Tags: function, lambda, scheme, lisp, racket

Everytime I see functions returning functions, the returned function is always a lambda. I'm wondering if I can have my function return a function that has a name to it.

Comment: Well, `define` is not a function, it is a syntactic form, so it cannot be "returned" from a function. However, to answer your question by its title, yes, you can return any function from a function, however it was created. Keep in mind, though, that functions created with `define` are still just lambdas; `define` just provides some extra syntactic sugar to make a common pattern easier.

Comment: The short answer is:  yes, you can do `(define (foo x) (define (bar ...) ...) bar)` and return the function that, *inside the definition of `foo`*, was bound to the variable `bar`.  Is that what you're asking?  This seems like it wouldn't have been hard to test, though.  Did you try something like this?  Did it not work as expected?

Comment: Sorry I had an error in my original question, question has been edited for clarity.

Comment: Joshua, I did not know that you needed to have the bar) at the end. Once I added that my code doesn't have an error.

What I'm wondering now is how to call my functions.  So I can easily call creator, but then how do I call chatter? The body of chatter involves from, to, and sent.

Comment: @romqA3 You call all functions in exactly the same way. If you create your function with `(define f (creator 1 2 3))`, you call it with `(f x y)`. (Using suitable parameters, of course.)

Answer (score 5):

The syntax that you are trying to use is correct, simply use the name of the inner function as value returned by the outer function. For instance you can write:

```
(define (incrementer x)
  (define (adder y)
    (+ x y))
  adder)

(define incrementer-by-1 (incrementer 1))
(define incrementer-by-2 (incrementer 2))

(incrementer-by-1 3)
(incrementer-by-1 10)
(incrementer-by-2 15)
```

As a comment says, keeping in mind that `(define (f x) y)` is just an abbreviation for `(define f (lambda(x) y))`, the previous function is equivalent to:

```
(define (incrementer x)
  (lambda (y)
    (+ x y)))
```

As another example, you can return a function which was previously defined:

```
(define (make-positive x)
  (abs x))

(define (make-negative x)
  (- (abs x)))

(define (same-signer x)
  (if (>= x 0)
      make-positive
      make-negative))

((same-signer 3) -2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small example.

```
#lang racket
(define (fun1) "Function 1")
(define (fun2) "Function 2")

(define (number->function n)
  (cond
    [(= n 1) fun1]
    [(= n 2) fun2]
    [else    (error 'number->function "expected 0 or 1 as input")]))

(number->function 1)
((number->function 1))
```

The output is:

```
#<procedure:fun1>
"Function 1"
```